# Unicode characters gets messed up when used as key in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios4

When I use the following keys Ä,Å,Ö in a NSMutableDictionary they get converted into "\U00c4", "\U00c5" and "\U00d6". Causing my software to miss the objects associated with the mentioned keys as I use the original form (Å, Ä and Ö) in the code. The language is Swedish and I want this to work for all countries, so the conversion isn't a desired behavior.

What am I doing wrong here?

How can I avoid the characters to be converted?

Code:

```
- (void)populateNavigationViewWithProjects:(id)projects
{
    [self.navigationViewItems removeAllObjects];
    BOOL keyExists = NO;
    NSString* firstLetterInProjectName = @"";
    for (id project in projects) {
        firstLetterInProjectName = [[[project valueForKey:@"name"] uppercaseString] substringToIndex:1];
        keyExists = [[self.navigationViewItems allKeys] containsObject:firstLetterInProjectName];
        if (keyExists) {
            [[self.navigationViewItems objectForKey:firstLetterInProjectName] addObject:project];
        }
        else {
            NSMutableArray* listOfProjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:project, nil];
            [self.navigationViewItems setValue:listOfProjects forKey:firstLetterInProjectName];
            [listOfProjects release];
        }
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

navigationViewItems is accessed in:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString* sectionTitle = [[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles] objectAtIndex:section];
    BOOL sectionContainsData = [[self.navigationViewItems allKeys] containsObject:sectionTitle];
    if (sectionContainsData) {
        return sectionTitle;
    }
    return @"";
}
```

Objects listed under Å,Ä and Ö won't be listed due to this.

Comment: Can you post the code you’re using? I’ve just tested `[d objectForKey:@"Ä"]` and it works correctly on Mac OS X.

Comment: I've added the code. I'm using navigationViewItems in "- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section" so the problem might lie in that.

Comment: Ah the problem lies in UILocalizedIndexedCollation since it doesn't contain unicode characters- Thanks. I was way off track here. :-)

Comment: When you figure out the solution yourself, post it as an answer (i.e., not in the question body) and then accept it! This will mark your question as answered and it won’t show up in the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1):

you could call  `-precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` before using the string.

[NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) function to deal with unicode content.

```
precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping:
decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping:
```